# Ranking (ordering value) of an observation in a matrix

Tags: matlab

I am trying to get the rank of an observation in a matrix, taking into account NaN's and values that can repeat themselfs.

E.g. if we have

```
A = [0.1 0.15 0.3; 0.5 0.15 0.1; NaN 0.2 0.4];

A =

    0.1000    0.1500    0.3000
    0.5000    0.1500    0.1000
    NaN       0.2000    0.4000
```

Then I want to get the following output:

```
B =

     1     2     4
     6     2     1
     NaN     3     5
```

Thus 0.1 is the lowest value (rank=1), whereas 0.5 is the highest value (rank = 6).

Ideally an efficient solution without loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `unique`. This sorts data by default, and you can get the index of the sorted unique values. This would replicate your tie behaviour, since identical values will have the same index. You can omit `NaN` values with logical indexing.

```
r = A;                                   % or NaN(size(A))
nanIdx = isnan(A);                       % Get indices of NaNs in A to ignore
[~, ~, r(~nanIdx)] = unique(A(~nanIdx))  % Assign non-NaN values to their 'unique' index

>> r = 
    [   1   2   4
        6   2   1
      NaN   3   5  ]
```

---

If you have the stats toolbox you can use [`tiedrank`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/tiedrank.html) function for a similar result.

```
r = reshape(tiedrank(A(:)), size(A)) % Have to use reshape or rank will be per-column

>> r = 
    [ 1.5,  3.5,  6.0
      8.0,  3.5,  1.5
      NaN,  5.0,  7.0 ]
```

This is not your desired result (as per your example). You can see that `tiedrank` actually uses a more conventional ranking system than yours, where a tie gives each result the average rank. For example a tied 1st and 2nd gives each rank 1.5, and the next rank is 3.

---

Comment: Incredible how quick it works! Just applied it on a large matrix where I did a loop on the unique values, and this solution decreased the time from 2s to 0.005493s

Comment: You can actually see the inner workings using `edit unique` (relevant lines are 188 to 296 in R2017b), and there isn't a loop in sight... built ins are often more rapid than a custom implementation because they have been heavily optimised by the MathWorks folks. Glad I could help